# AS3 Sprite Button Depth Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having trouble getting the sprite button to display in the proper depth. I suspect it may have something to do with my Loader objects but can't find a solution. When I trace the depth it is correct index of 3 but still shows up on index 0. Code between "Close Video Start and Close Video End comments Thank You.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

import flash.display.Shape; 
import flash.display.Sprite;

//----------------------------------- 300x250 Start ---------------------------------\\

//SWF Load and URL Request
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();  
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("_/media/300x250.swf"); 

//Function for Replay
function loadSWF():void {
//Add URL to Load Object
myLoader.load(url); 
//Index 0   
addChild(myLoader);  
//Loader Cordinates 
myLoader.x = 803;                                        
myLoader.y = 331;   
}

// Mask for Load Object 300x250
var maskSWF:Shape = new Shape(); 
maskSWF.graphics.lineStyle(); 
maskSWF.graphics.beginFill(0x0); 
maskSWF.graphics.drawRect(803, 331, 300, 250); 
maskSWF.graphics.endFill(); 
this.addChild(maskSWF); 

myLoader.mask = maskSWF; 

//----------------------------------- 300x250 End ---------------------------------\\

//----------------------------------- Video Start ---------------------------------\\

//Video Player Load and URL Request
var myLoaderVidPlay:Loader = new Loader();  
var urlVidPlay:URLRequest = new URLRequest("_/media/vid_player.swf");

//Timer Function to Play Video Player UI 
function timerListenerVidPlay (e:TimerEvent):void{
//Add URL to Load Object
myLoaderVidPlay.load(urlVidPlay);    
//Index 1
addChild(myLoaderVidPlay);

//Loader Cordinates 
myLoaderVidPlay.x = 803;                                        
myLoaderVidPlay.y = 331;     
}

//New Timer Object Video Background
var myTimerVidPlay:Timer = new Timer(1400,1);
myTimerVidPlay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListenerVidPlay);


//Creating NetConnection object - Set to null when local folder
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null);

//New NetStream
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 
function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    // ignore error 
}

//New Video Object
var vid:Video = new Video(); 

//Timer Function to Play Vid
function timerListenerVid (e:TimerEvent):void{
//Index 2   
ns.play("./_/media/vid.flv"); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns); 
addChild(vid);      
vid.x = 818;                                        
vid.y = 345;  
vid.width = 271;
vid.height = 153;
}


//New Timer Object Video
var myTimerVid:Timer = new Timer(1500,1);
myTimerVid.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListenerVid);


//------------------------------------ Video End ---------------------------------\\

//----------------------------------- Replay Start ---------------------------------\\

//Removes and Reloads SWFs for Replay
replay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, replayClickHandler);

//Replay Advertisement
function replayClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myLoader.unload();
    myLoaderVidPlay.unload();
    myTimerVidPlay.stop();
    //Closes Video Stream
    ns.close();

    loadSWF();
    myTimerVidPlay.start();
    myTimerVid.start();
}

//----------------------------------- Replay End ---------------------------------\\

//----------------------------------- Close Video Start ---------------------------------\\

var closeVid:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
closeVid.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, .5); 
closeVid.graphics.drawRect(703, 331, 300,250);
closeVid.graphics.endFill(); 
//Index 3
addChild(closeVid);
//trace(getChildIndex(this.closeVid));

//Adds hand cursor
closeVid.useHandCursor = true;
closeVid.buttonMode = true;

closeVid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickCloseVid);

function myClickCloseVid (e:MouseEvent):void{
    myTimerVidPlay.stop();
    myLoaderVidPlay.unload();
    //Closes Video Stream
    ns.close();
    removeChild(vid);
}

//----------------------------------- Close Video End ---------------------------------\\


//Start Functions
loadSWF();
myTimerVid.start();
myTimerVidPlay.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

well you are calling addChild(closeVid); before calling addChild(myLoader);

call addChild(closeVid); after calling loadSWF(); which calls addChild(myLoader);

That was solution to your problem.

Now, loadSWF? what kind of name it is? it is misleading and later (month, year) you will need to inspect the body of function ti find out what it does.

addChild in the function is also a bad idea - why? well it is root of your problem:) and this function does more than adding a child to a display list which should be kept separate.

Comment: I will take your advice and try to fix it. I didn't change some of the names from the example I learned from because I'm hacking this together as fast as I can to get a job and things have been looked over. I'm a graphic designer so I'm doing the best I can. I know this code must look like a disaster to developers. Sorry.